# Javascript underscore data format array of object

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

By using underscoreJS lib and manipulating some datas, i have this object

```
var data = {
  "2017-09-26": [
        {
            "id": 274281,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 274282,
            "value": 20
        }],
  "2017-09-27": [
        {
            "id": 274281,
            "value": 12
        },
        {
            "id": 274282,
            "value": 13
        }],
     }
```

i would like to obtain this result below by passing the keys as date in the child object and transform the value of id key as the new key of the value of value

```
   var data = [{  
                 date:"2017-09-26",
                 274281: 10,
                 274282: 20
              },
              {
                 date:"2017-09-27",
                 274281: 12,
                 274282: 13
              }]
```

Please does someone as an idea to help me to do this and ideally efficiently?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried coding this out at all yet?

Comment: yes i tried since few hours by different way. I am newbie with underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is in one line:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => ({date: key, ...data[key].reduce((p, c) => {p[c.id] = c.value; return p}, {})}))
```

Result:

```
[{
    "274281":10,
    "274282":20,
    "date":"2017-09-26"
},
{
    "274281":12,
    "274282":13,
    "date":"2017-09-27"
}]
```

Comment: thank u @CRice   can you please jsut explain the 
ellipsis in {date: key, ...data[key]

Comment: `...` is a destructuring assignment. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment In this case it's being used to copy the keys/values of the object produced via the `reduce` function into the object being returned by the map.

Comment: looks like it doesn't work in nodejs  sorry i forgit to specify

Answer (score 0):

You need nested loops. The first level creates the objects with the `date` property, then you loop over the objects in that value, and add the `id: value` properties to the result.

```
var newdata = _.map(data, (date, objects) => {
    res = {date: date};
    _.each(objects, obj => {
        res[obj.id] = obj.value;
    });
    return res;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from()` on the result of `Object.entries(data)` to create an array of objects by passing a callback function as the second argument.

Then for each sub-array, use `.reduce()` to create a new object from its members.

```js
var data = {
  "2017-09-26": [
    { "id": 274281, "value": 10 },
    { "id": 274282, "value": 20 }
  ],
  "2017-09-27": [
    { "id": 274281, "value": 12 },
    { "id": 274282, "value": 13 }
  ],
};

const result = Array.from(Object.entries(data), ([key, arr]) =>
  arr.reduce((res, {id, value}) =>
    Object.assign(res, {[id]: value})
  , {date: key})
);

console.log(result);
```

---

Here's one that's just about the same, but uses the new object literal spread syntax.

```js
var data = {
  "2017-09-26": [
    { "id": 274281, "value": 10 },
    { "id": 274282, "value": 20 }
  ],
  "2017-09-27": [
    { "id": 274281, "value": 12 },
    { "id": 274282, "value": 13 }
  ],
};

const result = Array.from(Object.entries(data), ([key, arr]) =>
  ({date: key, 
    ...Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(({id, value}) => ({[id]: value})))
  })
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: looks like it doesn't work in nodejs  sorry i forgit to specify

Comment: @llaid: Are you using an old version?